# eclipse upgrade breaks svn overlays in workspace

Tags: eclipse, svn, upgrade, workspace

Since I upgraded Eclipse to Indigo I lost svn overlays next to files and folders in PHP file explorer in PHP perspective of PDT.
Upgrading to newer Eclipse not helping it.
If I create new workspace and new project there overlays show properly.
How can I upgrade or fix this info in existing workspace? I really don't want to recreate all 30 projects in this workspace one by one ;o(

Thanks for ideas.

S.

Comment: doesn;t help its still without svn info after delete and reimport.